# open an inline color box link from js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox, adobe-edge

I need to open a colorbox link from js 
(the js is actually in an Adobe Edge document on the site)

normaly in html I would use this to open the inline color box with #id-6:

```
<a href="?width=90%&amp;height=90%&amp;inline=true#id-6" class="colorbox-inline init-colorbox-inline-processed cboxElement">test </a>
```

but I can't get it to work in JS 
I've not a lot of experience with JS so I tried some options
but none of the 5 below result in showing the inline color box

```
document.location.href="?width=90%&height=90%&inline=true#id-6";

window.open("?width=90%&height=90%&inline=true#id-6", "_self");

$.colorbox({width:"80%", height:"80%", inline:"true", href:"id-6"});

$.fn.colorbox({href:'#id-6', open:true, inline:true, width:'90%', height:'90%'});

jQuery().colorbox({width:"90%", height:"90%", inline:true, href:"?#id-6"});

...
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, found out how this works... maybe good for further references for integrations of Colorbox and Adobe Edge.

```
jQuery('div').colorbox({
    href: "#id-7", 
    inline:true, 
    innerWidth:'90%', 
    innerHeight:'90%', 
    open:true
});  
e.preventDefault();  
return false;
```

And make sure yo add the correct color box classes to the current div

colorbox-inline init-colorbox-inline-processed cboxElement